# Mongoose - deprecated mongodb@2.2.16: Please upgrade to 2.2.19 or higher?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Why do I keep getting this warning message below when I try to install [mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose)?

> npm WARN deprecated mongodb@2.2.16: Please upgrade to 2.2.19 or higher

json:

```
{
  "name": "dummy-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.4",
    "pug": "~2.0.0-beta3",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.7.6"
  }
}
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The npm package `mongodb` is a dependency of `mongoose`: it is automatically installed by npm when you install `mongoose`.

mongoose v4.7.6 depends on mongodb 2.2.16 (see [its `package.json` file](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/4.7.6/package.json#L26)), but there is a newer bugfix release available (2.2.19) which is why you see the warning.

As mongodb is a dependency of mongoose, you will have to wait for a mongoose maintainer to update the dependency: this is not an issue you have to fix in your code.

As a matter of fact, this issue is already tracked in mongoose's Github [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4865).